# Is the center of a compact Lie algebra precisely the set of vectors on which the Killing form is zero?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose a Lie algebra $\frak{g}$ has a killing form, $B$, which is negative semidefinite.  Suppose $B(X,X)=0$ for some $X\in \frak{g}$.  Is $X$ necessarily in the center of $\frak{g}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assumptions in the question are weaker than the ones in the title, and it depends on which one you choose as to whether the resulting statement it true or not:

If we only assume $B$ negative semidefinite, the statement is not true: If ${\mathfrak g}$ is nilpotent, then its Killing form vanishes completely, but ${\mathfrak g}$ is not necessarily abelian.

If we assume that ${\mathfrak g}$ is a compact Lie algebra, then the statement is true: any compact Lie algebra is reductive, so it splits as ${\mathfrak g} = {\mathfrak z}({\mathfrak g})\oplus [{\mathfrak g},{\mathfrak g}]$ with ${\mathfrak g}^{\prime} := [{\mathfrak g},{\mathfrak g}]$ semisimple compact. The restriction of the Killing form of ${\mathfrak g}$ to ${\mathfrak g}^{\prime}$ is the Killing form of ${\mathfrak g}^{\prime}$, which is negative definite. Hence any $X\in{\mathfrak g}$ with $B(X,X)=0$ must belong to ${\mathfrak z}({\mathfrak g})$.

*Edit* This might be shortened a bit, recalling how one shows that compact Lie algebras have negative semidefinite Killing forms: If $G$ is a compact Lie group with Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$, averaging yields an $\text{Ad}(G)$-invariant scalar product $\langle -,-\rangle$ on ${\mathfrak g}$. Then $\rho=\text{Ad}: G\to\text{GL}({\mathfrak g})$ maps to $O({\mathfrak g},\langle -,-\rangle)$, so $\text{d}(\rho)=\text{ad}: {\mathfrak g}\to{\mathfrak g}{\mathfrak l}({\mathfrak g})$ has image in ${\mathfrak o}({\mathfrak g},\langle -,-\rangle)$, the $\langle-,-\rangle$-skewsymmetric operators on ${\mathfrak g}$. Those have purely imaginary spectrum, so $\text{tr}(\text{ad}(X)^2)\leq 0$ for all $X\in{\mathfrak g}$, *with equality if and only if* $\text{ad}(X)\equiv 0$, i.e. $X\in{\mathfrak z}({\mathfrak g})$.

Comment: Thanks, @Hanno.  The argument in the edit fully answers  my question but I'm also trying to understand the third paragraph: Why is $\frak{g}'$ compact?  And then why is its Killing form negative *definite*? Or do we have to use the arguments in the edit for that?

Comment: @MarkCorrigan: A Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$ is compact if and only if it admits a positive definite associative form, and this inherits to any ideal, which is automatically a summand: Namely, given such a form $\langle -,-\rangle$, any ideal ${\mathfrak i}$ in ${\mathfrak g}$ is in fact a Lie algebra summand through the decomposition ${\mathfrak g}={\mathfrak i}\oplus{\mathfrak i}^{\perp}$, where $\perp$ is taken w.r.t. $\langle-,-\rangle$, and the restriction of $\langle-,-\rangle$ to ${\mathfrak i}$ is again a positive definite associative form.

Comment: @MarkCorrigan: For a *semi-simple*, compact Lie algebra, the Killing form is not only negative semi-definite, but also non-degenerate by Cartan's criterion - hence it is negative definite.